# How do I get Siri to ignore a particular contact that shares someone else's name?

Tags: contacts, siri

I have two people in my contacts with the same first name (let's call them John). One person, John Appleseed, I talk to all the time. The other one, John Doe, I haven't spoken to in years.

When I tell Siri something like "Where is John?" or "Text John What's up?", I'm frequently asked "Which one? John Appleseed, or John Doe?"

Other than deleting the unfortunate person who shares the same first name as someone I talk to all the time, how can I teach Siri that "John" *always* refers to John Appleseed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving the contact a nickname (Add Field > Nickname) in your Contacts, and then use that nickname when ordering Siri to text that person. Alternatively, put a character in front of old John's name so Siri never gets confused (e.g., xJohn or oldJohn or #John).

Comment: I didn't test giving the "real" person a nickname, but I put a random Emoji character at the front of the "ignored" person's first name and Siri stopped asking me which one I mean.